# Cube Movement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to modify the below script to change direction only when the player swipes. Is it possible? (The script is rolling the cube in all directions on the flat floor) !!!!!

**Something like the below picture:**

[image]

```
        public float tumblingDuration = 0.2f;

        void Update ()
      {
        var dir = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            dir = Vector3.forward;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            dir = Vector3.back;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            dir = Vector3.left;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            dir = Vector3.right;
        if (dir != Vector3.zero && !isTumbling)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Tumble(dir));
        }
    }
    bool isTumbling = false;
    IEnumerator Tumble(Vector3 direction)
    {
    isTumbling = true;
    var rotAxis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, direction);
    var pivot = (transform.position + Vector3.down*0.5f ) +    direction*0.5f;
    var startRotation = transform.rotation;
    var endRotation   = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90.0f, rotAxis)*startRotation;
    var startPosition = transform.position;
    var endPosition   = transform.position + direction;
    var rotSpeed = 90.0f/tumblingDuration;
    var t = 0.0f;
    while ( t < tumblingDuration )
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.RotateAround(pivot, rotAxis, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.rotation = endRotation;
    transform.position = endPosition;
    isTumbling = false;
    }
```

Comment: What does this code do? What have you tried so far? Please fix the formatting of the code.

Comment: @Maakep I wrote what the script do!

Answer (score 1):

You should use Quaternion.Slerp

```
cube.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(cube.transform.rotation, cube.transform.rotation + dir * new Vector3(90, 0, 0), /*time*/ 2f);
```

Comment: I need to delete some lines of the code and put this?

Comment: Delete the IEnumerator. The code put in if where you were calling IEnumerator